# Finding function parameters of function that is not on top of stack using windbg

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

Here is the part of call stack returned by kd command. I want to know what parameters were passed to myutil!myclass::somefunc. How do I get those parameters using windbg?

```
0a11f614  0a11f634
0a11f618  7686592c rpcrt4!Invoke+0x2a
0a11f61c  0e7b2c98
0a11f620  03edad48
0a11f624  03edaba8
0a11f628  00000206
0a11f62c  00000003
0a11f630  0a11f820
0a11f634  0a11fa38
0a11f638  768e05f1 rpcrt4!NdrStubCall2+0x2ea
0a11f63c  6dbc12b2*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for myutil
 myutil!myclass::somefunc
```

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Comment: Do you have the pdbs? Is windbg able to find them & associate them with the right binaries? From the stack, it doesn't appear so.

Comment: You need the pdbs with private symbols then you can do `kp` which will print the parameters for each frame, in addition to this you need to set the symbol path to point to the pdbs

Comment: Also remember to use debug build as release build's optimization could  cause incorrect output.

Comment: Having the private symbols would make it easier but the parameters can be retrieved by looking at the stack *(depending on calling convention but true most of the time)*. Using `kbnf`, although not guaranteed to show the right information would be a good start to.

Comment: Since you apparently don't have the symbols for this it'll take a little detective work. This looks like 32-bit code, so you have five different calling conventions to distinguish from. Who cleans up the stack for this function? You can do a uf myutil!myclass:somefunc to for hints. That said, myclass seems to be a class, so it may be the C++ this calling convention. In which case, if fixed arguments, the arguments are passed right to left on the stack, with this pointer in ECX.

Comment: [Continued]  Do a .frame /c /r [n] to restore the registers to the nth frame where myclass:somefunc is being called. Then check the stack for passed arguments.

Comment: I have private symbols for myutil library and I have added path to them in symbol path and windbg displayed "OK" against that after reloading.. is there any other way to check? Also, the output of kd and kp are completely different.. output of kp does not even mention myutil. Any idea why that must be?

Comment: by "Also, the output of kd and kp are completely different.." I meant kd and kp display completely different stack. Any reason why would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

`about the stack being different`

There is no reason that the stack shown by kd and kp would be different. They are essentially different representation on the same data.
If you paste the stack here may be we will be point out whats going on!
Are you sure you running both commands in the same place ?

`how to check if symbols are loaded correctly`

execute the command : "lml" to see for which binaries, symbols have been loaded.

`Coming to your original question`

kP is the simplest way to see the parameters that are being passed to the function.

another way to do the same thing is 
a. run "kn" so that you see frame numbers in the stack trace.

b. move to the frame of interest by doing ".frame

c. now dump the variables using "dv"

If you are really passionte you can read about paramter passing. Then all you would need is the EBP + some assembly code reading to figure out which parameters we passed.